How to create a multivariable sweep in HFSS using PyAEDT?
I'm trying to model a metasurface made of square loops and want to test it's S-parameters (amplitude and phase responses) for different loop sizes. Since loops have 2 degrees of freedom, I need to sweep over both inner and outer lengths (or outer length and loop width).
I tried to create 2 variable sweeps like that:
setup = hfss.create_setup("loop")
setup.props["Frequency"] = "10GHz"
setup.props["MaximumPasses"] = 10 
hfss.parametrics.add(variable = "l_outer",
                     start_point = loop_sweep_start, 
                     end_point = loop_sweep_stop, 
                     step = loop_sweep_step, 
                     variation_type='LinearStep')
hfss.parametrics.add(variable = "width", 
                     start_point = width_sweep_start, 
                     end_point = width_sweep_stop, 
                     step = width_sweep_step, 
                     variation_type='LinearStep')

but it creates 2 different parametric sweeps and doesn't computes all the combinations.
